# SQL Server Function to Split Full Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have scoured SO for a resolution to my problem with getting this function to run properly, but I mostly see solutions regarding the use of the function and not as many in creating the function. I have already created the function, so that's why it reads 'ALTER FUNCTION' at the top of my code. The end goal is to parse out First Name, Middle Initial, and Last Name.

I keep getting an **incorrect syntax error near the first 'END' in the CASE statement** regarding the parsing of the FirstName. I apologize if this is such an easy fix but I just cannot figure out what I am missing. Any help in error recognition or a cleaner syntax would be much appreciated for a beginner like myself.

Also, the 2nd SET statement towards the bottom is just a simple function(already written before I got here) that CamelCases the output.

Sorry about the first comment. Here are some sample names that I have been using and I want to parse these from one column into 3 columns. First, middle, and last name.

Carlton J Smith
Charmane Thorn
Deel S Shah
Curtis Brennan
Allie F Allison
Alex Finde
Tina D Page
Jackie Russell

I tried adding two more SET statements but it still is giving me the same syntax error around the first CASE statement. Anything else I could provide to give more context? Thanks for the prompt responses.

```
ALTER FUNCTION fn_clean_Name_Split (@source VARCHAR(255))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @target VARCHAR(255) = @source  
    DECLARE @index INT = CHARINDEX(' ',@target)

    SET @target =
        CASE
            WHEN @index <> LEN(@target)
            THEN LEFT(@target, @index)
        END AS FirstName,
        CASE    
            WHEN @index <> LEN(@target) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@target)) + 1 
            THEN SUBSTRING(@target, @index + 1, LEN(@target) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@target)) - @index)
        END AS MI,
        CASE
            WHEN @index <> LEN(@target) - @index + 1 
            THEN RIGHT(@target, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@target))) AS LastName,
            ELSE @target    

    SET @target = dbo.fn_standardize_CamelCase(@target)

    RETURN @target
END
```

Comment: well, you are trying to assign 3 different values to the same variable

Comment: Considering you are working with names, be sure to read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: You also declare an column alias within a `CASE` expression (`LastName`) and then don't close that `CASE` with an `END`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

A `set` is used to set the value of a single variable, not multiple variables.  This is easy to work around; you can just use multiple `set` statements.

You can set multiple variables using `select`.  That is a nice convenience.  But you cannot both set values and return values in the same statement.

You have a function, so you don't want a query that returns values anyway.

Comment: @Moose Better if you edit your question with sample data and desired results.